# Is $O$ in $f \in O(g)$ a total partial order on the set of functions?

Tags: real-analysis

1. Given the set of functions defined
   on a subset in $\mathbb{R}$ and
   taking values in $\mathbb{R}$, I was
   wondering if $O$ as in $f \in O(g)$
   is a total partial order? By total, I would like to know if every two functions can be compared by $O$? Is it
   acting like $\geq$ on $\mathbb{R}$?
2. How about $\Omega$, $\Theta$, $o$, $\omega$ and $\sim$? Are they acting 
   like $\leq$, $==$, $>$, $<$ and $==$
   respectively?

For definitions, see [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Family_of_Bachmann.E2.80.93Landau_notations).
Thanks and regards!

Comment: The answers have shown this to be false, but I wonder, what if we add a constraint such as restricting to increasing functions?

Comment: @Harry Altman: You still won't have anti-symmetry: $2x=O(x)$, $x=O(2x)$, but $x\neq 2x$.

Comment: Well, yes, but that's obvious. I'm wondering about totality.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It is not a *partial* order since you don't have anti-symmetry: $f\in O(g)$ and $g\in O(f)$ does not imply $f=g$.

When you identify functions which are equivalent in that sense, you end up with a partial order (reflexivity and transitivity are obvious), but this this will not be a *total* order: for instance, $\sin(x)$ and $\cos(x)$ are not comparable.

Summing up, $O$ only defines a *preorder* on the set of functions from $\mathbb R$ to $\mathbb R$.

Answer (score 4):

None of those is a total order.
Take $f(n)=\begin{cases}
n & \text{n odd}\\
n^2 &\text{n even}\end{cases}$

 $g(n)=\begin{cases}
n^2 & \text{n odd}\\
n &\text{n even}\end{cases}$